# Strange error installing Psyco in Python

Tags: python, psyco

I have installed psyco in one machine with no problem, but i'm getting an strange error while installing in one other machine.
I'm not able to use easy_install, since it gives me an error:

```
C:\Python26\Downloads\psyco-1.6>easy_install psyco
Searching for psyco
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/psyco/
Reading http://psyco.sourceforge.net/
Best match: psyco snapshot
Downloading http://wyvern.cs.uni-duesseldorf.de/psyco/psyco-snapshot.tar.gz
error: Can't download http://wyvern.cs.uni-duesseldorf.de/psyco/psyco-snapshot.t
ar.gz: 404 Not Found
```

So, I download the last version 1.6 and did "python setup.py install". I have already used it several times with no problem. I get the follwing messages:

```
C:\Python26\Downloads\psyco-1.6>python setup.py install
PROCESSOR = 'i386'
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psyco._psyco' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 180, in <module>
    **kwds )
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 577, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_exte
nsions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 499, in build_exte
nsion
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 449, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 359, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 275, in query_vcvarsal
l
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that psyco has extension modules that need to be built. The error message you're getting is not what I would expect, but it seems to indicate that it's not finding the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, required (at least recommended over other compilers) for building extension modules for Python 2.6.

If you really want to build from sources, I suggest you download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition or Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 trial.

You would probably be better off reading [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/849963-psyco-available-python-2-6-a), and downloading a pre-compiled binary from someone in the community who has already compiled it.

Edit: I just noticed that on the [Psyco home page](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) there is a link to Python 2.6 [pre-compiled binaries by Michael Foord](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#psyco). These would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I already installed MS visual 2008, since I was getting another error (not finding a .bat file). The pre-compiled versions are only for 32bits, not 64, unfortunately. I'll read the thread you suggested. thanks

Comment: @user210481, Did you read the front page of Psyco's website? "Just for reference, Psyco does not work on any 64-bit systems at all." If you need it to work on 64-bit systems, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get around this problem too (while trying to install another module). The problem is the script msvc9compiler.py is trying to find and vcvarsall.bat which is under a folder like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC` which in turn is trying to find and execute a script under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools` in my case `vcvars32.bat`. This script is setting-updating certain variables: *PATH, LIB* and 2 others that are never set/updated in your case.

My workaround was to find the *.bat manually and run it in the prompt from which I would then run the installation command. The variables are set correctly this way but only during the session of the command prompt.

Try running `echo %LIB%`, before and after running the script, to see that the variable is indeed set.